# Adding a default string in $project stage is giving error

Tags: json, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Here is my $project stage

```
{
$project : {
"receiptNumber" : "$billNo",
"transactionStatus" : "SALE"
}
}
```

Here sale is just a default string which is giving me error,

```
"FieldPath 'SALE' doesn't start with $",
```

Sale is not a field in my document it just a string,
Cant i give a default string in $project stage???

Comment: Use *[$literal](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/)*

Comment: Thanku that worked